# Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?

Tags: bash, shell, csh, tcsh

I'm trying to write a shell script that, when run, will set some environment variables that will stay set in the caller's shell.

```
setenv FOO foo
```

in csh/tcsh, or

```
export FOO=foo
```

in sh/bash only set it during the script's execution.

I already know that

```
source myscript
```

will run the commands of the script rather than launching a new shell, and that can result in setting the "caller's" environment.

But here's the rub:

I want this script to be callable from either bash or csh.  In other words, I want users of either shell to be able to run my script and have their shell's environment changed.  So 'source' won't work for me, since a user running csh can't source a bash script, and a user running bash can't source a csh script.

Is there any reasonable solution that doesn't involve having to write and maintain TWO versions on the script?

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro that's not working (at least on osx), as 'export' is interpreted by bash as a file name.

Comment: see @Humberto Romero 's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28489593/881375 in this thread

Comment: The title of this Q should be changed - the main differentiation is **using two different shells**, the title does not reflect that.

Comment: Anwered here for both Linux and Windows: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/change-environment-of-a-running-process/502129#502129

Comment: how, and this is not rhetorical, is this a duplicate of questions asked years later?

Comment: Probably the best solution would be [nor to use csh](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html), but I guess you don't want to hear this. In your case, I would create two different files, one for bash/ksh and maybe zsh, and the other one for csh/tcsh.

Comment: to dump the full environment of a subshell, use `declare -p` for variables and `declare -pf` for functions, see also [How to list all variables names and their current values?](https://askubuntu.com/a/277969/877276)

Answer (score 332, accepted):

Your shell process has a copy of the parent's environment and no access to the parent process's environment whatsoever. When your shell process terminates any changes you've made to its environment are lost. Sourcing a script file is the most commonly used method for configuring a shell environment, you may just want to bite the bullet and maintain one for each of the two flavors of shell.

Comment: @KrisRandall Actually the answer is correct!!
source script.sh == . script.sh

Comment: See also: [env2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/env2/), "a unix perl script to convert environment variables between scripting languages." This is specifically linked from the [Environment Modules home page](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) under "Related tools"

Comment: Is it possible to run the Nodejs app through the debugger when instantiating the app this way?   This is what I do, but can't seem to get it to run via launch.json:

"./path-to-script/script.sh .env npm start"

Comment: what do you mean, by saying "you may just want to bite the bullet and maintain one for each of the two flavors of shell."?

Comment: @andreagalle He says you may need to compromise and keep a separate shell with all the customization you want in it. So basically you will keep different .bashrc files for every different shell you have, and maybe keep a short script or shortcut to invoke the shell.

Answer (score 621):

Use the "dot space script" calling syntax. For example, here's how to do it using the full path to a script:

```bash
. /path/to/set_env_vars.sh
```

And here's how to do it if you're in the same directory as the script:

```bash
. set_env_vars.sh
```

These execute the script under the current shell instead of loading another one (which is what would happen if you did `./set_env_vars.sh`). Because it runs in the same shell, the environmental variables you set will be available when it exits.

This is the same thing as calling `source set_env_vars.sh`, but it's shorter to type and might work in some places where `source` doesn't.

Comment: In other words, dot space is a replacement for bash's `source` in other shells.

Comment: I've noticed that this will not work if one will pipe the output e.g      ". ./script.sh | tee out.log"

Comment: I have no idea how or why this works but it works perfectly.

Comment: Jip Should be at the top. Just stating the obvious.. if the script is in your PWD then it has the form of dot space dot eg       .  ./localscript.sh

Comment: dot is just `source`

Comment: @ozma Good catch, that's wasted a few hours for me this afternoon!

Comment: This does not work ... if `set_env_vars.sh` does `export MY_VAR=123` , `$MY_VAR` is still blank in the calling script ... I don't understand this answer

Comment: `. ./set_env_vars.sh` right?

Comment: The question states that he already knows what source is and it's obviously not what he is looking for. This is not the correct answer for the question being asked.

Comment: Upvoted since this answers the question in the title (for bash), even though it doesn't answer the full question. It also clearly explains why `source` works.

Comment: When I source the bash script, it says "export: Command not found". Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 61):

You're not going to be able to modify the caller's shell because it's in a different process context.  When child processes inherit your shell's variables, they're
inheriting copies themselves.

One thing you can do is to write a script that emits the correct commands for tcsh
or sh based how it's invoked.  If you're script is "setit" then do:

```
ln -s setit setit-sh
```

and

```
ln -s setit setit-csh
```

Now either directly or in an alias, you do this from sh

```
eval `setit-sh`
```

or this from csh

```
eval `setit-csh`
```

setit uses $0 to determine its output style.

This is reminescent of how people use to get the TERM environment variable set.

The advantage here is that setit is just written in whichever shell you like as in:

```
#!/bin/bash
arg0=$0
arg0=${arg0##*/}
for nv in \
   NAME1=VALUE1 \
   NAME2=VALUE2
do
   if [ x$arg0 = xsetit-sh ]; then
      echo 'export '$nv' ;'
   elif [ x$arg0 = xsetit-csh ]; then
      echo 'setenv '${nv%%=*}' '${nv##*=}' ;'
   fi
done
```

with the symbolic links given above, and the eval of the backquoted expression, this has the desired result.

To simplify invocation for csh, tcsh, or similar shells:

```
alias dosetit 'eval `setit-csh`'
```

or for sh, bash, and the like:

```
alias dosetit='eval `setit-sh`'
```

One nice thing about this is that you only have to maintain the list in one place.
In theory you could even stick the list in a file and put `cat nvpairfilename` between "in" and "do".

This is pretty much how login shell terminal settings used to be done:  a script would output statments to be executed in the login shell.  An alias would generally be used to make invocation simple, as in "tset vt100".  As mentioned in another answer, there is also similar functionality in the INN UseNet news server.

Comment: I think this might be on the right track.  But I don't quite know what should be in 'setit' that will allow it to run correctly from either shell.  Can you spell out a little more what you had in mind?

Comment: Basically, it would check $0 and move into the appropriate part of the script based on what name it was called with.

Comment: I think what Thomas is saying, you write the `setit` script in one language, but it then outputs a language specific set of instructions that must be `eval'd` by the calling process.

Comment: Aha, I see what you are doing now.  Ugh, that's clever but awkward.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This is awesome. My problem is a lot easier than that: changing env variables without using . or source. A simple `alias gg='. gg $1'` fixes that.

Comment: You don't need the whole complex link system. Just use the $SHELL variable.

Comment: The SHELL variable isn't perfectly reliable.  Example:  on my ArchLinux system I run tcsh and SHELL is set to /bin/tcsh.  Starting a bash and echoing SHELL still gives /bin/tcsh and ditto invoking bash as sh.  SHELL only works in shells that bother to set it or on systems with rc files that set it, and not all do.

Comment: I wanted to shorten my shell prompt whenever required but not permanently. Just added a variable, say PSS in my .bashrc that contained the modifed prompt in quotes, and now I just do PS1=$PSS whenever required. I am happy with how this works for a single variable so if anyone finds this useful..

Answer (score 50):

In my .bash_profile I have :

```bash
# No Proxy
function noproxy
{
    /usr/local/sbin/noproxy  #turn off proxy server
    unset http_proxy HTTP_PROXY https_proxy HTTPs_PROXY
}


# Proxy
function setproxy
{
    sh /usr/local/sbin/proxyon  #turn on proxy server 
    http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8118/
    HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
    https_proxy=$http_proxy
    HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy
    export http_proxy https_proxy HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY
}
```

So when I want to disable the proxy, 
the function(s) run in the login shell and sets the variables
as expected and wanted.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed (well, I had to change the port number ;).

Answer (score 36):

It's "kind of" possible through using gdb and [setenv(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv), although I have a hard time recommending actually doing this. (Additionally, i.e. the most recent ubuntu won't actually let you do this without telling the kernel to be more permissive about ptrace, and the same may go for other distros as well).

```
$ cat setfoo
#! /bin/bash

gdb /proc/${PPID}/exe ${PPID} <<END >/dev/null
call setenv("foo", "bar", 0)
END
$ echo $foo

$ ./setfoo
$ echo $foo
bar
```

Comment: Kjetil, dude, this is fantastic.  I am really enjoying your script right now.

Comment: This is awesome! But how to do it in Mac?

Comment: thanks, as 1-liner it's: `gdb -nx -p $$ --batch -ex 'call setenv("foo", "bar")' > & /dev/null`

Comment: Interesting approach. When I have the time I'll look into how do to it from OS X and update.

Answer (score 17):

This works — it isn't what I'd use, but it 'works'.  Let's create a script `teredo` to set the environment variable `TEREDO_WORMS`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
export TEREDO_WORMS=ukelele
exec $SHELL -i
```

It will be interpreted by the Korn shell, exports the environment variable, and then replaces itself with a new interactive shell.

Before running this script, we have `SHELL` set in the environment to the C shell, and the environment variable `TEREDO_WORMS` is not set:

```
% env | grep SHELL
SHELL=/bin/csh
% env | grep TEREDO
%
```

When the script is run, you are in a new shell, another interactive C shell, but the environment variable is set:

```
% teredo
% env | grep TEREDO
TEREDO_WORMS=ukelele
%
```

When you exit from this shell, the original shell takes over:

```
% exit
% env | grep TEREDO
%
```

The environment variable is not set in the original shell's environment.  If you use `exec teredo` to run the command, then the original interactive shell is replaced by the Korn shell that sets the environment, and then that in turn is replaced by a new interactive C shell:

```
% exec teredo
% env | grep TEREDO
TEREDO_WORMS=ukelele
%
```

If you type `exit` (or <kbd>Control-D</kbd>), then your shell exits, probably logging you out of that window, or taking you back to the previous level of shell from where the experiments started.

The same mechanism works for Bash or Korn shell.  You may find that the prompt after the exit commands appears in funny places.

---

Note the discussion in the comments.  This is not a solution I would recommend, but it does achieve the stated purpose of a single script to set the environment that works with all shells (that accept the `-i` option to make an interactive shell).  You could also add `"$@"` after the option to relay any other arguments, which might then make the shell usable as a general 'set environment and execute command' tool.  You might want to omit the `-i` if there are other arguments, leading to:

```
#!/bin/ksh
export TEREDO_WORMS=ukelele
exec $SHELL "${@-'-i'}"
```

The `"${@-'-i'}"` bit means 'if the argument list contains at least one argument, use the original argument list; otherwise, substitute `-i` for the non-existent arguments'.

Comment: Um, this is kind of drastic:  you're replacing the login shell.  If you're going to do this... you should check into how this impacts session and process group and other things.  For example:  what do you think happens to managed child processes?

Comment: Undoubtedly - that's why I said I would not use it.  If you exec twice, you've not lost session or process group information; that is based on PID and PID doesn't change. In a profile or login file, it gets you through a common language environment setting script. But, as I said, I would not use it.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried to do for my specific case ! This technique seems to be used by clearcase when doing "cleartool setview", which is what I try to emulate. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You could simply invoke a new shell, rather than replace the existing shell.

Comment: @JonathonHill: You could (run a new shell as an ordinary command instead of doing `exec`).  The main reason not to do so is that you have a stray level of shell, so you'd have to do an extra control-D to logout in that window.

Comment: Right, which was perfectly acceptable in my particular use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You should use modules, see http://modules.sourceforge.net/

EDIT: The modules package has not been updated since 2012 but still works ok for the basics. All the new features, bells and whistles happen in lmod this day (which I like it more): https://www.tacc.utexas.edu/research-development/tacc-projects/lmod

Comment: We use modulefiles extensively here, and csh/bourne-ish support is one reason.  We have legacy csh scripts, bash scripts and python scripts, and they all get environment variable settings from the same modulefiles, rather than having an env.csh, env.sh, env.py set of scripts with the extra maintenance that entails. 

Additionally, modulefiles allow your environment to reflect version dependencies:  if you need need to change to version 3 from version 4 of a tool, instead of resetting all your env vars manually, you  can just module swap and everything changes over.

Comment: I couldnt find examples on how to use it, every attempt I made was unsuccessful, any tips?

Comment: @AquariusPower after so many years I don't recommend modules anymore, but its moral successor, which is lmod see https://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/lmod -- I think its docs are also better than the older modules, see if trying it is better for you

Comment: @LiDong - yes it has not been updated since 2012 but still works ok for the basics. All the new features, bells and whistles happen in lmod this day (which I like it more): https://www.tacc.utexas.edu/research-development/tacc-projects/lmod

Comment: It lives again: http://modules.sourceforge.net/. See also [env2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/env2/), billed as a "script to convert environment variables between scripting languages."

Answer (score 11):

Another workaround that I don't see mentioned is to write the variable value to a file.

I ran into a very similar issue where I wanted to be able to run the last set test (instead of all my tests).  My first plan was to write one command for setting the env variable TESTCASE, and then have another command that would use this to run the test.  Needless to say that I had the same exact issue as you did.

But then I came up with this simple hack:

First command ( `testset` ):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
  echo $1 > ~/.TESTCASE
  echo "TESTCASE has been set to: $1"
else
  echo "Come again?"
fi
```

Second command (`testrun` ):

```
#!/bin/bash

TESTCASE=$(cat ~/.TESTCASE)
drush test-run $TESTCASE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can instruct the child process to print its environment variables (by calling "env"), then loop over the printed environment variables in the parent process and call "export" on those variables.

The following code is based on [Capturing output of find . -print0 into a bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array)

If the parent shell is the bash, you can use

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
    export "$line"
done < <(bash -s <<< 'export VARNAME=something; env -0')
echo $VARNAME
```

If the parent shell is the dash, then `read` does not provide the -d flag and the code gets more complicated

```
TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
mkfifo $TMPDIR/fifo
(bash -s << "EOF"
    export VARNAME=something
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
        echo $(printf '%q' "$line")
    done < <(env -0)
EOF
) > $TMPDIR/fifo &
while read -r line; do export "$(eval echo $line)"; done < $TMPDIR/fifo
rm -r $TMPDIR
echo $VARNAME
```

Answer (score 3):

Under OS X bash you can do the following:

Create the bash script file to unset the variable

```
#!/bin/bash
unset http_proxy
```

Make the file executable

```
sudo chmod 744 unsetvar
```

Create alias

```
alias unsetvar='source /your/path/to/the/script/unsetvar'
```

It should be ready to use so long you have the folder containing your script file appended to the path.

Comment: Any reason you don't simply use `alias unsetvar='unset http_proxy'`? Or better yet create a function `unsetvar () { unset http_proxy; }`

Comment: This is not only for OS X. This can work for Linux too. This answer would also be better if you wrote what files you are working in.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke another one Bash with the different bash_profile. 
Also, you can create special bash_profile for using in multi-bashprofile environment.

Remember that you can use *functions* inside of bashprofile, and that functions will be avialable globally.
for example, "function user { export USER_NAME $1 }" can set variable in runtime, for example: user olegchir && env | grep olegchir

Comment: None of this will affect the calling shell.

Comment: @Ignacio, in this case you don't need to call scripts for setting environment variables. "Calling" shell will set the variable itself. But if we still need to separate setters from the main bashrc code, we can split all this functions into the separate file, and include it as a library (eg "source ru.olegchir.myproject.environment.setters.sh" in the .bashrc).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use "Environment Modules" (http://modules.sourceforge.net/). This unfortunately introduces a third language into the mix. You define the environment with the language of Tcl, but there are a few handy commands for typical modifications (prepend vs. append vs set). You will also need to have environment modules installed. You can then use `module load *XXX*` to name the environment you want. The module command is basically a fancy alias for the `eval` mechanism described above by Thomas Kammeyer. The main advantage here is that you can maintain the environment in one language and rely on "Environment Modules" to translate it to sh, ksh, bash, csh, tcsh, zsh, python (?!?!!), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I created a solution using pipes, eval and signal.

```
parent() {
    if [ -z "$G_EVAL_FD" ]; then
            die 1 "Rode primeiro parent_setup no processo pai"
    fi
    if [ $(ppid) = "$$" ]; then
            "$@"
    else
            kill -SIGUSR1 $$
            echo "$@">&$G_EVAL_FD
    fi
}
parent_setup() {
    G_EVAL_FD=99
    tempfile=$(mktemp -u)
    mkfifo "$tempfile"
    eval "exec $G_EVAL_FD<>'$tempfile'"
    rm -f "$tempfile"
    trap "read CMD <&$G_EVAL_FD; eval \"\$CMD\"" USR1
}
parent_setup #on parent shell context
( A=1 ); echo $A # prints nothing
( parent A=1 ); echo $A # prints 1
```

It might work with any command.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any answer documenting how to work around this problem with cooperating processes.  A common pattern with things like `ssh-agent` is to have the child process print an expression which the parent can `eval`.

```
bash$ eval $(shh-agent)
```

For example, `ssh-agent` has options to select Csh or Bourne-compatible output syntax.

```
bash$ ssh-agent
SSH2_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-era/ssh2-10690-agent; export SSH2_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH2_AGENT_PID=10691; export SSH2_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 10691;
```

(This causes the agent to start running, but doesn't allow you to actually use it, unless you now copy-paste this output to your shell prompt.)  Compare:

```
bash$ ssh-agent -c
setenv SSH2_AUTH_SOCK /tmp/ssh-era/ssh2-10751-agent;
setenv SSH2_AGENT_PID 10752;
echo Agent pid 10752;
```

(As you can see, `csh` and `tcsh` uses `setenv` to set varibles.)

Your own program can do this, too.

```
bash$ foo=$(makefoo)
```

Your `makefoo` script would simply calculate and print the value, and let the caller do whatever they want with it -- assigning it to a variable is a common use case, but probably not something you want to hard-code into the tool which produces the value.

Answer (score 2):

It's not what I would call outstanding, but this also works if you need to call the script from the shell anyway. It's not a good solution, but for a single static environment variable, it works well enough.

1.) Create a script with a condition that exits either 0 (Successful) or 1 (Not successful)

```
if [[ $foo == "True" ]]; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
```

2.) Create an alias that is dependent on the exit code.

```
alias='myscript.sh && export MyVariable'
```

You call the alias, which calls the script, which evaluates the condition, which is required to exit zero via the '&&' in order to set the environment variable in the parent shell.

This is flotsam, but it can be useful in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, that is correct -- only 'eval' doesn't fork another shell.  However, from the point of view of the application you're trying to run in the modified environment, the difference is nil: the child inherits the environment of its parent, so the (modified) environment is conveyed to all descending processes.

Ipso facto, the changed environment variable 'sticks' -- as long as you are running under the parent program/shell.

If it is absolutely necessary for the environment variable to remain after the parent (Perl or shell) has exited, it is necessary for the parent shell to do the heavy lifting.  One method I've seen in the documentation is for the current script to spawn an executable file with the necessary 'export' language, and then trick the parent shell into executing it -- always being cognizant of the fact that you need to preface the command with 'source' if you're trying to leave a non-volatile version of the modified environment behind.  A Kluge at best.

The second method is to modify the script that initiates the shell environment (.bashrc or whatever) to contain the modified parameter.  This can be dangerous -- if you hose up the initialization script it may make your shell unavailable the next time it tries to launch.  There are plenty of tools for modifying the current shell; by affixing the necessary tweaks to the 'launcher' you effectively push those changes forward as well.
Generally not a good idea; if you only need the environment changes for a particular application suite, you'll have to go back and return the shell launch script to its pristine state (using vi or whatever) afterwards.

In short, there are no good (and easy) methods.  Presumably this was made difficult to ensure the security of the system was not irrevocably compromised.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you cannot alter the environment of the parent process, but it seems like what you want is an environment with custom environment variables and the shell that the user has chosen.

So why not simply something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FOO=foo $SHELL
```

Then when you are done with the environment, just `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use aliases

```
alias your_env='source ~/scripts/your_env.sh'
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this many years ago. If I rememeber correctly, I included an alias in each of .bashrc and .cshrc, with parameters, aliasing the respective forms of setting the environment to a common form.

Then the script that you will source in any of the two shells has a command with that last form, that is suitable aliased in each shell.

If I find the concrete aliases, I will post them.

Comment: its been years..

Answer (score -12):

Other than writings conditionals depending on what $SHELL/$TERM is set to, no.  What's wrong with using Perl?  It's pretty ubiquitous (I can't think of a single UNIX variant that doesn't have it), and it'll spare you the trouble.

Comment: How does Perl solve the problem?  The Perl program still can't set the environment variables of the calling shell, can it?

Comment: No.  It can, however, set it through Local::Env, then call your shell script with system() or backticks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that system() or backticks would be making a new child shell, not calling to the shell that launched the Perl script.

Comment: perl is just one of many scripting languages, but why limit the user as it may really not be the language of the script that the user is attempting to have the environment variables available to, especially if a large script is already written?