# Shell: find should ignore blanks

Tags: shell, console, find

I've a shellscript, that I run from an NSTask, that I build dynamically. Everything works fine besides one thing:

If the filename contains a blank, it's ignored by the find-command. I use it like that: 'find -iname *.xxx'.

If the filename looks something like  'aaa bbb.xxx', than it's not found.

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Marcus

Comment: Yeah, no, that's not it.

Comment: I've done my best to answer your question, but if my answer doesn't help out, you're going to have to post code illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` does not care if your file names have spaces in them. That's not your problem.

If you're actually calling it as typed in your question (`find -iname *.xxx`), then the problem is that you need to quote the file name pattern to protect it from shell expansion: `find -iname '*.xxx'`. Note the quotes around the pattern; they're essential.

Otherwise, the problem is very likely in how you're handling the file names you're getting back. For example, this won't work:

```
for f in `find -iname '*.xxx'`; do
   echo "file: $f"
done
```

you'll see that the backtick operator actually splits on spaces (or, `$IFS`, actually) and you get back two "files": 'aaa' and 'bbb.xxx'.

Comment: The `-print0` option to `find` might be useful here.  Note that it requires some extra work in whatever processes the output of `find`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yep, often does. And if the "whatever process" is the rest of the shell script, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array

Answer (score 0):

Escape the Pattern like this:

```
find -iname '*.xxx' -print
```

please consider +1 if it helped. thanks