# In Bash, how to find the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor?

Tags: bash, file-io

In a Bash-script, is it possible to open a file on "the lowest-numbered file descriptor not yet in use"?

I have looked around for how to do this, but it seems that Bash always requires you to specify the number, e.g. like this:

```
exec 3< /path/to/a/file    # Open file for reading on file descriptor 3.
```

In contrast, I would like to be able to do something like

```
my_file_descriptor=$(open_r /path/to/a/file)
```

which would open 'file' for reading on the lowest-numbered file descriptor not yet in use and assign that number to the variable 'my_file_descriptor'.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I know this thread is old, but believe that the best answer is missing, and would be useful to others like me who come here searching for a solution.

Bash and Zsh have built in ways to find unused file descriptors, without having to write scripts. (I found no such thing for dash, so the above answers may still be useful.)

Note: this finds the lowest unused file descriptor > 10, not the *lowest* overall.

```
$ man bash /^REDIRECTION (paragraph 2)
$ man zshmisc /^OPENING FILE DESCRIPTORS
```

Example works with bsh and zsh.

Open an unused file descriptor, and assign the number to $FD:

```
$ exec {FD}>test.txt
$ echo line 1 >&$FD
$ echo line 2 >&$FD
$ cat test.txt
line 1
line 2
$ echo $FD
10  # this number will vary
```

Close the file descriptor when done:

```
$ exec {FD}>&-
```

The following shows that the file descriptor is now closed:

```
$ echo line 3 >&$FD
bash: $FD: Bad file descriptor
zsh: 10: bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for not letting the age of this thread stop you from posting this! In fact, your answer is the first (of this thread) to <i>really</i> provide what I was looking for when I posted my question some 18 months ago; the other answers are really "work-arounds". However, the {FD}> feature that is used in your solution is not supported in Bash 4.0 or earlier. It was introduced in Bash 4.1-alpha, so the work-arounds presented in the other answers may be valuable anyhow to someone being stuck with Bash 4.0 or earlier.

Comment: Nice! Also works for the typical `flock` scenario: `( flock $FD; echo got the lock; ) {FD}> mylock`

Comment: I've been using mkfifo for this. Not really a solution, as the fifos don't have "storage". So Thanks a bunch for this!

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work in bash 3. `bash: exec: {FD}: not found`

Comment: Hello, what happens if there is no file descriptor available?

Answer (score 7):

If it is on Linux, you can always read the `/proc/self/fd/` directory to find out the used file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction, Basile! I subsequently used it and wrote my own answer to this question.

Comment: Yep, and if you're not on Linux you may be able to use `/dev/fd`. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 5):

I revised my original answer and now have a one line solution for the original post.
The following function could live in a global file or sourced script (e.g. ~/.bashrc):

```
# Some error code mappings from errno.h
readonly EINVAL=22   # Invalid argument
readonly EMFILE=24   # Too many open files

# Finds the lowest available file descriptor, opens the specified file with the descriptor
# and sets the specified variable's value to the file descriptor.  If no file descriptors
# are available the variable will receive the value -1 and the function will return EMFILE.
#
# Arguments:
#   The file to open (must exist for read operations)
#   The mode to use for opening the file (i.e. 'read', 'overwrite', 'append', 'rw'; default: 'read')
#   The global variable to set with the file descriptor (must be a valid variable name)
function openNextFd {
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "${FUNCNAME[0]} requires a path to the file you wish to open" >&2
        return $EINVAL
    fi

    local file="$1"
    local mode="$2"
    local var="$3"

    # Validate the file path and accessibility
    if [[ "${mode:='read'}" == 'read' ]]; then
        if ! [ -r "$file" ]; then
            echo "\"$file\" does not exist; cannot open it for read access" >&2
            return $EINVAL
        fi
    elif [[ !(-w "$file") && ((-e "$file") || !(-d $(dirname "$file"))) ]]; then
        echo "Either \"$file\" is not writable (and exists) or the path is invalid" >&2
        return $EINVAL
    fi

    # Translate mode into its redirector (this layer of indirection prevents executing arbitrary code in the eval below)
    case "$mode" in
        'read')
            mode='<'
            ;;
        'overwrite')
            mode='>'
            ;;
        'append')
            mode='>>'
            ;;
        'rw')
            mode='<>'
            ;;
        *)
            echo "${FUNCNAME[0]} does not support the specified file access mode \"$mode\"" >&2
            return $EINVAL
            ;;
    esac

    # Validate the variable name
    if ! [[ "$var" =~ [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ]]; then
        echo "Invalid variable name \"$var\" passed to ${FUNCNAME[0]}" >&2
        return $EINVAL
    fi

    # we'll start with 3 since 0..2 are mapped to standard in, out, and error respectively
    local fd=3
    # we'll get the upperbound from bash's ulimit
    local fd_MAX=$(ulimit -n)
    while [[ $fd -le $fd_MAX && -e /proc/$$/fd/$fd ]]; do
        ((++fd))
    done

    if [ $fd -gt $fd_MAX ]; then
        echo "Could not find available file descriptor" >&2
        $fd=-1
        success=$EMFILE
    else
        eval "exec ${fd}${mode} \"$file\""
        local success=$?
        if ! [ $success ]; then
            echo "Could not open \"$file\" in \"$mode\" mode; error: $success" >&2
            fd=-1
        fi
    fi

    eval "$var=$fd"
    return $success;
}
```

One would use the foregoing function as follows to open files for input and output:

```
openNextFd "path/to/some/file" "read" "inputfile"
# opens 'path/to/some/file' for read access and stores
# the descriptor in 'inputfile'

openNextFd "path/to/other/file" "overwrite" "log"
# truncates 'path/to/other/file', opens it in write mode, and
# stores the descriptor in 'log'
```

And one would then use the preceding descriptors as usual for reading and writing data:

```
read -u $inputFile data
echo "input file contains data \"$data\"" >&$log
```

Comment: Thanks Coren, for your time and effort in carrying through this impressively thorough investigation! As the owner of the question I've marked your answer as the "accepted" one. Fascinating, though, that it was so hard to solve this!

Comment: Coren, just adding a comment here so maybe you get notified and come here. Thought you would be interested to see Weldabar's solution, which is definitely the way to do it if using Bash 4.1-alpha or later. (Weldabar's solution is not supported by Bash 4.0 or earlier.)

Answer (score 5):

I needed to support *both* bash v3 on Mac and bash v4 on Linux and the other solutions require either bash v4 or Linux, so I came up with a solution that works for both, using `/dev/fd`.

```
find_unused_fd() {
  local max_fd=$(ulimit -n)
  local used_fds=" $(/bin/ls -1 /dev/fd | sed 's/.*\///' | tr '\012\015' '  ') "
  local i=0
  while [[ $i -lt $max_fd ]]; do
    if [[ ! $used_fds =~ " $i " ]]; then
      echo "$i"
      break
    fi
    (( i = i + 1 ))
  done
}
```

For example to dup stdout, you can do:

```
newfd=$(find_unused_fd)
eval "exec $newfd>&1"
```

Comment: I like the idea. I golfed it down to a 1 liner. `/bin/ls -1 /dev/fd | sed 's/.*\///' | sort -n | awk 'n<$1{exit}{n=$1+1}END{print n}'`

Comment: Very nice.  From this I learned (and confirmed) that "/dev/fd" is custom for every distinct instance of shell.  @"Bruno Bronsky" why the 'sed'?

Answer (score 2):

In Basile Starynkevitch's answer to this question, on Nov 29 2011, he writes:

> *If it is on Linux, you can always read the /proc/self/fd/ directory to find out the used file descriptors.*

Having done several experiments based on reading the fd directory, I have arrived at the following code, as the "closest match" to what I was looking for. What I was looking for was actually a bash one-liner, like

```
my_file_descriptor=$(open_r /path/to/a/file)
```

which would find the lowest, unused file descriptor *AND* open the file on it *AND* assign it to the variable. As seen in the code below, by introducing the function "lowest_unused_fd", I at least get a "two-liner" (FD=$(lowest_unused_fd) *followed by* eval "exec $FD<$FILENAME") for the task. I have NOT been able to write a function that works like (the imaginary) "open_r" above. If someone knows how to do that, please step forward! Instead, I had to split the task into two steps: one step to *find* the unused file descriptor and one step to *open* the file on it. Also note that, to be able to place the *find* step in a function ("lowest_unused_fd") and have its stdout assigned to FD, I had to use "/proc/$$/fd" instead of "/proc/self/fd" (as in Basile Starynkevitch's suggestion), since bash spawns a subshell for the execution of the function.

```
#!/bin/bash

lowest_unused_fd () {
    local FD=0
    while [ -e /proc/$$/fd/$FD ]; do
        FD=$((FD+1))
    done
    echo $FD
}

FILENAME="/path/to/file"

#  Find the lowest, unused file descriptor
#+ and assign it to FD.
FD=$(lowest_unused_fd)

# Open the file on file descriptor FD.
if ! eval "exec $FD<$FILENAME"; then
    exit 1
fi

# Read all lines from FD.
while read -u $FD a_line; do
    echo "Read \"$a_line\"."
done

# Close FD.
eval "exec $FD<&-"
```

Comment: glad this answer is still around, it is still needed.  The year is 2020, I have Max OS X with the latest update (Catalina) but my Bash version is still not 4.1 or higher.  It is stuck at 3.2.57.  I think Apple switched to "zsh", but that's no excuse.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Many modern shells, such as KornShell 93r+, Bash 4.1α+, & Zsh 4.3.4+, provide a native solution: `exec {var}< filename`.  This assigns an unused descriptor (greater than 9) to `var`, which can be used as `<&$var` or `{var}<&-`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030546) for details.  Neither Ash nor Dash support this feature.

The following solution avoids using OS-specific features and even other binaries; instead, it uses only the tools provided directly by the shell, for maximum portability.  It aims for compatibility with [POSIX.1-2017 Shell & Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) and works on `ash` (BusyBox v1.16.1), `bash` (v3.00), `dash` (v0.5.8), `ksh` (93u), & `zsh` (v5.9).

```
unused_fd() (
    FD=${1:-3}
    MAX=$(ulimit -n)
    while [ $FD -lt $MAX ]
    do
        if ! ( : <&$FD ) 2>&-
        then
            printf %d $FD

            [ "$(eval "echo $FD<&-")" ] && return 8
            return 0
        fi
        FD=$(( FD + 1 ))
    done
    return 24
)
```

This function prints an unused file descriptor on standard output, if found; otherwise, it prints nothing.  It exits zero if the printed file descriptor can be used in `n<`, `n>`, etc.; non-zero otherwise.

## USAGE

```
FILENAME=foo
(                                   # Spawn subshell (unnecessary on Bash or Zsh)
    FD=$(unused_fd) || exit         # Find an available descriptor
    eval "exec $FD<\"\$FILENAME\""  # Open descriptor, if one was available
    …                               # Use descriptor, if one was opened
)                                   # Descriptor closes with subshell termination
```

**Note:** While Bash supports redirects to any file descriptor, most shells limit redirects to file descriptors 0 – 9.  If more descriptors are needed, and the shell supports it, use the aforementioned `exec {var}< filename`, `exec {var}> filename`, etc. instead and bypass the need for `unused_fd` (and `eval`).

If a descriptor cannot be found, `$FD` may be empty and `exec $FD<…` could overwrite standard input.  Protect against this by checking the exit of `unused_fd` and skipping `exec` if it fails.

This usage of `eval` (note `\"` & `\$`) supports redirecting files with whitespace or any special characters (e.g. `'`, `"`, `\`) in the path when using a variable.

### POSIX, `exec`, & subshells

Per [§ 2.8.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01), a redirection error (such as *File not found*) with special built-in utilities, like `exec`, shall cause the shell to exit (or stop processing) immediately.  To avoid stopping the whole script when an error occurs, wrap the sections using the file descriptor in a subshell; the subshell will exit on error and the remaining script can continue running.  All operations with the descriptor must happen within the subshell that opened it.

**Note:** Some shells, like Bash and Zsh, break POSIX compliance by providing an error without terminating; on these shells, it would be worthwhile to check the exit of `exec` for failures.  However, the lack of termination also means the subshell wrapper can be omitted *if* portability is not a concern.

---

## DESIGN BREAKDOWN

### Limitations on `$(open_r)`

`FD=$(open_r "$FILENAME")` cannot work because `$()` forks a command substitution subshell; it's the subshell, not the shell assigning a value to `FD`, that will open a new file descriptor.  Since subshells cannot modify the parent shell's environment, the opened file descriptor cannot be used outside the subshell [0].

If a command substitution subshell is avoided, as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15219148), a function *similar to* `open_r` can exist.

### Developing `unused_fd`

Executing `$COMMAND <&3` when file descriptor 3 is not open will cause the shell itself to emit an error message along the lines of `sh: 3: Bad file descriptor`.  Moreover, when this happens, `$COMMAND` is never started and the shell sets `$?` to a non-zero value.  Therefore, if `$COMMAND` runs, we know file descriptor 3 was already open.

To ensure the non-zero exit is from the shell (and not the command), run a command that can never exit non-zero: the `:` built-in.  With `: <&3`, the shell will exit non-zero if (and, ideally, only if) file descriptor 3 cannot be duplicated, and an unused descriptor is the primary reason duplication would fail [1].

Alas, a redirection (duplication) error on `: <&3` causes POSIX compliant shells to terminate command processing immediately, killing the running script.  To keep the shell script running, perform the check in a subshell that can die instead: `( : <&3 )`.

To silence the error from the shell, close standard error on the subshell with `2>&-`.  Closing the descriptor provides compatibility with systems that do not have `/dev/null` [2,3].

To avoid overriding a shell's variables, wrap the compound list in a subshell (i.e. `()`) instead of using the current process environment (i.e. `{;}`) for the function definition [4].

Most shells, other than Bash, only parse `n<`, etc. as a single token when `n` is 0–9.  Larger numbers, like `10`, get parsed as two separate tokens: `10` & `<`.  Check for this with `echo`, which will print nothing (other than newline) if `10<&-` is parsed as a unit, but will print out `10` if `10<&-` is parsed as `10` & `<&-`; let the caller know via the exit value [2].

### Avoiding Data Stream Corruption

When a file descriptor is duplicated on POSIX compliant systems, the original and duplicated descriptors refer to the same file description and a change to one changes the other(s); see [dup2](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2)(2).  Thus, it is important to make sure any commands run by `unused_fd` will not write to, or read from, the file descriptor being tested for availability.  Since the `:` built-in does not execute a command, there is no worry about a `read`(2) or `write`(2) call causing corruption.

If the `:` built-in is superseded, as was infamously done for a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb), this requirement may no longer be met.  However, since `:` is commonly used in scripts with the expectation of not executing a command, any modification to `:` would have ramifications far beyond the `unused_fd` function.

### Write-Only File Descriptors

If a write-only file descriptor is created (e.g. `exec 3>/path/to/file`), it is not possible to read from that descriptor, even if it is duplicated.  How, then, does `: <&3` not immediately error out?

On POSIX systems, shells generally treat `n<&m` & `n>&m` identically, simply calling `dup2(m, n)` without assessing if the directionality makes sense.  The same is also true when closing file descriptors.

With this setup, it is only when something tries to read from the write-only file descriptor that an error will occur (in the command that called `read`(2)).  Since the `:` built-in doesn't read (or write) anything, this error is avoided.

### Footnotes

[0] It is possible for a process to `send` a file descriptor to another process (e.g. its parent) using a special connector, like UNIX domain sockets or D-Bus.  Doing this requires the shell to `recv` the value, which also cannot happen in a `$()` subshell, as the received descriptor would close when that subshell terminates.  Thus, some logic must happen in the shell before or after `FD=$(open_r …)`, regardless.  Such a solution is likely to be more verbose than the USAGE presented.

[1] As a special built-in, `:` does not *need* to call `fork`(2), `execve`(2), or any other system calls that might return a surprise error in extreme conditions.  This would, ideally, leave the `dup2`(2) system call as the only source of error that can occur, but individual implementations may vary.  Regardless, *under normal operating conditions*, the only error expected would be from `dup2` and that error would be either `EBADF` or, if the shell is not programmed to retry, from a race condition (i.e. `EINTR` or `EBUSY`).

[2] Attempting to close an already closed file descriptor will *not* cause an error (per POSIX.1-2017 Shell & Utilities § 2.7.6).

[3] Even if the subshell dies from an error during `write`(2) when the subshell prints an error message (due to standard error's closure), this will only happen if the subshell was going to exit non-zero anyway.  Thus, closing should be functionally equivalent to redirecting to `/dev/null`.

[4] The behavior of `local` is undefined, per [POSIX.1-2017 Shell & Utilities § 2.9.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01):

> (1.) b. If the command name matches the name of a utility listed in the following table, the results are unspecified.  … local …

Answer (score 0):

Apple Mac OS X is not Linux.  I don't see any '/proc' file system on OS X.

I guess one answer is to use "zsh", but I want to have a script that works on both OS X (aka BSD) and Linux in "bash".  So, here I am, in the year 2020, with the latest version of OS X, which at this moment is Catalina, and I realize that Apple seems to have abandoned maintenance of Bash long ago; apparently in favor of Zsh.

Here is my multi-OS solution to find the lowest unused file descriptor on Apple Mac OS X or Linux.  I created an entire Perl script, and in-lined it into the Shell script.  There must be a better way, but for now, this works for me.

```
lowest_unused_fd() {
  # For "bash" version 4.1 and higher, and for "zsh", this entire function  
  # is replaced by the more modern operator "{fd}", used like this:
  #    exec {FD}>myFile.txt; echo "hello" >&$FD;
  if [ $(uname) = 'Darwin' ] ; then
    lsof -p $$ -a -d 0-32 | perl -an \
      -e 'BEGIN { our @currentlyUsedFds; };' \
      -e '(my $digits = $F[3]) =~ s/\D//g;' \
      -e 'next if $digits eq "";' \
      -e '$currentlyUsedFds[$digits] = $digits;' \
      -e 'END { my $ix; 
            for( $ix=3; $ix <= $#currentlyUsedFds; $ix++) {  
              my $slotContents = $currentlyUsedFds[$ix];
              if( !defined($slotContents) ) { 
                last; 
              } 
            } 
            print $ix;
          }' ;
  else 
    local FD=3
    while [ -e /proc/$$/fd/$FD ]; do
      FD=$((FD+1))
    done
    echo $FD
  fi;
}
```

The `-an` options to Perl tells it to (`-n`) run an implied `while()` loop that reads the file line by line and (`-a)` auto-split it into an array of words which, by convention, is named `@F`.  The `BEGIN` says what to do before that `while()` loop, and the `END` says what to do after.  The `while()` loop picks out field `[3]` of each line, reduces it to just its leading digits, which is a port number, and saves that in an array of port numbers that are currently in use, and therefore are unavailable.  The `END` block then finds the lowest integer whose slot is not occupied.

**Update:** After doing all that, I actually am not using this in my own code.  I realized that the answer from KingPong and Bruno Bronsky is far more elegant.  However, I will leave this answer in place; it might be interesting to somebody.