# exec close file descriptor not found error

Tags: bash, exec, eval

I just use `exec {fd}<>myfile` to open a file and get the fd. After using, I want to close it with `exec $fd<&-`, but bash error "exec: 10: not found".Why this happen? At last I use `eval "exec $fd<&-"`,this works.

Comment: or `exec {fd}<&-`?

Comment: It do works.Where can I find some doc? I try to bash man page but got nothing.

Comment: It's in the section _REDIRECTION_, where it says: _Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by  a word of the form {varname}_. `$fd` is not a _varname_, but a _parameter expansion_.

Comment: See [In Bash, how to find the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8297415/4154375).