# for name in `ls` and filenames with spaces

Tags: bash, special-characters, filenames

next code doesnt work because of spaces in file names, How to fix?

```
IFS = '\n'
for name in `ls `
do
    number=`echo "$name" | grep -o "[0-9]\{1,2\}"`
    if [[ ! -z "$number" ]]; then
        mv "$name" "./$number"
    fi
done
```

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#line-75

Comment: GNU coreutils added `ls --zero` (i.e., end each output line with NUL and not newline "\n")(as of 2022-06-11). This avoid the issues with filenames containing spaces. See [ls source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just don't use command substitution: use `for name in *`.

Comment: Note that this may fail in an empty directory. Thee loop will be executed once with `name="*"`. Not a problem in this particular case though.

Comment: If it does turn out to be a problem, `shopt -s nullglob` will cause `*` to expand to zero words if there are no matches.

Comment: if I wanted to get the files in a specific order, such as with `| sort` or `| shuf`, the "just use globbing" advice seems pretty useless.

Answer (score 23):

Replace

```
for name in `ls`
```

with:

```
ls | while read name
```

**Notice**: bash variable scoping is awful. If you change a variable inside the loop, it won't take effect outside the loop (in my version it won't, in your version it will). In this example, it doesn't matter.

**Notice 2**: This works for file names with spaces, but fails for some other strange but valid file names. See Charles Duffy's comment below.

Comment: "If you change a variable inside the loop, it won't take effect outside the loopIf you change a variable inside the loop, it won't take effect outside the loop" -- if you use your construct, yes, because whatever is after the pipe is launched in a subshell. It is therefore expected that it has a different variable scope.

Comment: I think bash's behavior here is erratic. If you understand it, and it seems like you (i.e. fge) do, then you know what to expect. But I learned it the hard way, it it still looks strange to me.

Comment: `ls | while read name` is wrong. It doesn't correctly handle filenames with literal backslashes, or filenames with literal newlines, or filenames with leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: @ugoren, ...it's not even really a question of deliberate scoping rules, but a question of what pipelines are and what they mean; the rules just fall out. `foo | bar` means "run a subprocess foo, and a subprocess bar, with the output of the first subprocess connected to the input of the second subprocess". Since things are happening in subprocesses, of *course* they can't impact the parent process's variables or state. (The above is actually not *quite* true -- the POSIX sh standard doesn't specify that all pipeline components *must* be subprocesses -- but it's a good first approximation).

Comment: (...to clarify the distance between approximation and truth: To have a reasonable implementation, it's effectively mandatory that either all components, or all components but one, run in a subprocess; bash takes the "all components" approach unless the `lastpipe` option introduced in 4.2 is enabled and certain other prerequisites are met; ksh runs the last component of a pipeline in the parent shell, and puts all the others in subprocesses; other implementations of the standard may differ further).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for the clarification. If you try to think of Bash as a programming language, with variables, functions and return values, you get awful scoping laws. If you think of it as a way to invoke programs, your explanation makes perfect sense.

Comment: As Charles mentioned, a `ls | while read` won't cope if the script encounters filenames containing any manner of special characters.  If a more general solution is required, using find -print0 might be a better option, as described in Gordon's answers to [capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array).  Using a while read does cope nicely with the possibility that the number of arguments might exceed the maximum line length,  it's my preference when handling unbounded numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like **two potential issues**:

First, the IFS variable and it's assignment should not have space in them. Instead of

`IFS = '\n'` it should be `IFS=$'\n'`

Secondly, `for name in ls` will cause issues with filename having `spaces` and `newlines`. If you just wish to handle `filename` with `spaces` then do something like this

`for name in *`

I don't understand the significance of the line

```
number=`echo "$name" | grep -o "[0-9]\{1,2\}"`
```

This will give you numbers found in `filename with spaces` in `new lines`. May be that's what you want.

Comment: Actually, it should be `IFS=$'\n'` -- without the `$`, `\n` doesn't get interpreted as a newline, but as a literal backslash and the letter "n".

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to move to use `find`.

```sh
find /foo/path/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" | while read name
do
    #do your stuff with $name
done
```