# Allowing punctuation characters in directory and file names in bash

Tags: bash, special-characters

What techniques or principles should I use in a bash script to handle directories and filenames that are allowed to contain as many as possible of

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

and space?

I guess `/` is not a valid filename or directory name character in most linux/unix systems?
So far I have had problems with `!`, `;`, `|`,  (a space character) and `'` in filenames.

Comment: What issue do you encounter?  How do you read the filenames?

Comment: [for name in `ls` and filenames with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8645546/608639), [for loop through files with spaces and some special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33172934/608639), [Deleting filenames that have space and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50618130/608639), [How do I enter a file or directory name containing spaces or special characters in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/984801), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `/` is not valid, as is the null-byte `\0`.  There is no way around that limitation (besides file system hacking).

All other characters can be used in file names, including such surprising characters as a newline `\n` or a tab `\t`.  There are many ways to enter them so that the shell does not understand them as special characters.  I will give just a pragmatic approach.

You can enter most of the *printable* characters by using the singlequote `'` to to quote them:

```
date > 'foo!bar["#$%&()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'
```

Of course, you cannot enter a singlequote this way, but for this you can use the doublequote `"`:

```
date > "foo'bar"
```

If you need to have both, you can end one quotation and start another:

```
date > "foo'bar"'"bloh'
```

Alternatively you also can use the backslash `\` to escape the special character directly:

```
date > foo\"bar
```

The backslash also works as an escaper withing doublequotes, it does not work that way within singlequotes (there it is a simple character without special meaning).

If you need to enter non-printable characters like a newline, you can use the dollar-singlequote notation:

```
date > $'foo\nbar'
```

This is valid in bash, but not necessarily in all other shells.  So take care!

Finally, it can make sense to use a variable to keep your strange name (in order not to have to spell it out directly:

```
strangeName=$(xxd -r <<< "00 41 42 43 ff 45 46")
date > "$strangeName"
```

This way you can keep the shell code readable.

*BUT* in general it is not a good idea to have such characters in file names because a lot of scripts cannot handle such files properly.

To write scripts fool-proof is not easy.  The most basic rule is the quote variable usage in doublequotes:

```
for i in *
do
    cat "$i" | wc -l
done
```

This will solve 99% of the issues you are likely to encounter.

If you are using `find` to find directory entries which can contain special characters, you should use `printf0` to separate the output not by spaces but by null-bytes.  Other programs like `xargs` often can understand a list of null-byte separated file names.

If your file name can start with a dash `-` it often can be mistaken as an option.  Some programs allow giving the special option `--` to state that all following arguments are no options.  The more general approach is to use a name which does not start with a dash:

```
for i in *
do
    cat ./"$i" | wc -l
done
```

This way, a file named `-n` will not run `cat -n` but `cat ./-n` which will not be understood as the option `-n` given to `cat` (which would mean "number lines").

Answer (score 0):

Always quote your variable substitutions. I.e. not `cp $source $target`, but `cp "$source" "$target"`. This way they won't be subject to word splitting and pathname expansion.

Specify "--" before positional arguments to file operation commands. I.e. not `cp "$source" "$target"`, but `cp -- "$source" "$target"`. This prevents interpreting file names starting with dash as options.

And yes, "/" is not a valid character for file/directory names.