# for loop through files with spaces and some special characters

Tags: bash, for-loop, pipe, special-characters, filenames

I need to run the following command with a for loop

```
cat Locate\ Message.eml | ./locatePipe.php
```

I am trying the following however it seems to break on the first space in the file name

```
for i in $(find -name "*.eml"); do cat $i | ./locatePipe.php; done
```

Some of the file names contain "@", "()", "-", ".", "[]", " ' " if that matters

Comment: [Allowing punctuation characters in directory and file names in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17143729/608639), [for name in `ls` and filenames with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8645546/608639), [for loop through files with spaces and some special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33172934/608639), [Deleting filenames that have space and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50618130/608639), [How do I enter a file or directory name containing spaces or special characters in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/984801), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-exec` option

```
find -name '*.eml' -exec cat {} + | ./locatePipe.php
```

Comment: I need to use a for loop because it's too many to process at once. I end up with a memory issue this method

Comment: Then use `find -name '*.eml' -exec bash -c 'cat {} | ./locatePipe.php' \;`

Comment: `-exec cat {} +` will pass as many files as possible to each invocation of `cat`; you should have substantially fewer processes than if you use a for loop, which will start one `cat` per file.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this using the following command

```
find -name '*.eml' | while read email; do cat "$email" | ./locatePipe.php; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bash` 4, just skip using `find`:

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.eml; do
    cat "$i"
done | ./locatePipe.php
```