# mv a file from textpad that have space and special character

Tags: linux, sh

How to move ( mv ) a file that have space and special character - linux command

- file.txt contains are.

  04 Security @test.pdf

  05 Security @test.pdf

my command are below:

```
cat $DIR/file.txt | read line; do

mv $line ""$line{//[ ()@$]/_}" /$DIR/OUT done
```

Your expertise really appreciated,

Comment: Fix the quotes you have.

Comment: Remove the slash from before `$DIR`

Comment: What you want is `sed 's/[ ()@$]/_/g' <"$DIR/file.txt >/$DIR/OUT`

Comment: thanks , i'll try it.. sed is a stream editor. A stream editor is used to perform basic text transformations on an input stream (a file, or input from a pipeline).   https://www.computerhope.com/unix/used.htm

Comment: Or `mv "$line" "${line//[ ()@$]/_}"`. Always quote your variables, especially if they may contain whitespace.

Comment: @fndong - when you do try it -- remove (or add matching) quotes for the one I inadvertently failed to match.

Comment: [Allowing punctuation characters in directory and file names in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17143729/608639), [for name in `ls` and filenames with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8645546/608639), [for loop through files with spaces and some special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33172934/608639), [Deleting filenames that have space and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50618130/608639), [How do I enter a file or directory name containing spaces or special characters in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/984801), etc.

Comment: It seem its not work at all : sed 's/[ ()@$]/_/g' $DIR/file.txt > /$DIR/OUT
-bash:  /dir/OUT : Is a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command reads each line from `file.txt`, then renames the files, substituting `_` for each special character.

```
$ while read line ; do mv "$DIR/$line" "$DIR/${line//[ ()@$]/_}" ; done < file.txt
```

Comment: Hi @Rob , i followed your example , but I doesn't  need to add the substituting :    while read file; do
mv "$line" $DIR/; done < file.txt   , its working fined for move the space and special character... weird.. but thanks..

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Since you appeared to have attempted substitution in your example, I assumed that's what you wanted. Since my answer *doesn't* answer your question, you should unaccpet it.

Comment: Hi @Rob, sorry lead you misunderstanding.

Files name:
04 Security @test.pdf


This codes can't move file based on file.txt that have space and special character
`cat $DIR/file.txt | while read line; do
mv $line /$DIR/OUT `

mv: cannot stat 04: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat Security: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat @test.pdf.pdf: No such file or directory


and

This codes can cater space and special character

` while read line; do
mv "$line" $DIR/; done < file.txt
done `