# Remove exact string from files in folder using grep

Tags: linux, grep

I've got the following code:

```
cd /home/pi/.attract/romlists; for file in *.tag ; do grep -v -F 'Arcade Snooker [AGA]' $file > $file1.tmp && mv -f $file1.tmp $file; done
```

This works well to remove the fixed string "Arcade Snooker [AGA]" from a file such as "Amiga.tag".  However, it does not remove the string from "Atari 800.tag" or from any other file that has a "space" in its name.  The result for "Atari 800.tag" is the following error:

```
grep: Atari: No such file or directory
grep: 800.tag: No such file or directory
```

What changes do I need to make to the code please to get it to remove "Arcade Snooker [AGA]" from "Atari 800.tag" and from other such files containing spaces in their names?

I would prefer to have one line of code only please as I have it now.

Thanks.

Comment: [for name in `ls` and filenames with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8645546/608639)

Comment: I don't know why you downvoted my question.  The response you have provided does not fix my code.  The answer I upvoted fixes the code and does so on one line as I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the variables if the file names contain spaces...

```
cd /home/pi/.attract/romlists; for file in *.tag ; do grep -v -F 'Arcade Snooker [AGA]' "$file" > "$file1.tmp" && mv -f "$file1.tmp" "$file"; done
```