# Properly handle lists of files with whitespace in filename

Tags: bash, loops, whitespace, filenames

I want to iterate over a list of files in Bash and perform some action. The problem: the file names may contain whitespace, which creates an obvious problem with wildcards or `ls`:

```
touch a\ b
FILES=* # or $(ls)

for FILE in $FILES; do echo $FILE; done
```

yields

```
a
b
```

Now, the conventional way to handle this is to use `find … -print0` instead. However, this only works (well) in conjunction with `xargs -0`, not with Bash variables / loops.

My idea was to set `$IFS` to the null character to make this work. However, the comp.unix.shell seems to think that [this is impossible in bash](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.unix.shell/rNX500nae3c/discussion).

Bummer. Well, it’s theoretically possible to use another character, such as `:` (after all, `$PATH` uses this format, too):

```
IFS=$':'
FILES=$(find . -print0 | xargs -0 printf "%s:")

for FILE in $FILES; do echo $FILE; done
```

(The output is slightly different but fair enough.)

However, I can’t help but feel that this is clumsy and that there should be a more *direct* way of doing this. **I’m looking for a more direct way of accomplishing this, preferably using wildcards or `ls`.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to store the file list as an array, rather than a string (and be sure to double-quote all variable substitutions):

```
files=(*)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

If you want to generate an array from `find`'s output (e.g. if you need to search recursively), see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array/1120952#1120952).

Comment: Can you tell me what the advantage of this method over Collin’s is? – Actually, for my specific purpose there’s a pretty obvious advantage since I also need the *count* of the files, which is rather easier to obtain with arrays. But apart from that, what’s the advantage?

Comment: Mine works.  Collin's only appears to; it's actually just storing the wildcard, not a list of files.

Comment: I can’t follow. Collin’s method works just fine for me. That he stores the wildcard doesn’t matter, does it? That’s just how variables in Bash work anyway.

Comment: Maybe I should've said "mine works the way I expect it to."  I guess it comes down to what you're trying to do: if you want to store a list of files, use mine; if you want to store a file pattern (and generate a list of matching files later), use Collin's.  But if you use Collin's as though it stored a list of files, you're going to have trouble: things like the "list" changing as files are added and removed, or as you `cd` around, etc.  Counting entries is another example: a pattern matches any number of files, while a list contains a specific number of entries.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference, I wasn't entirely sure what was going on under the hood, but could tell the glob worked :-P

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what you have in the first example works fine for me in Msys Bash, Cygwin and on my Fedora box:

```
FILES=*
for FILE in $FILES
do
    echo $FILE
done
```

Comment: This isn't actually storing the file list in the variable, just the unexpanded wildcard.  `FILES=*; echo "$FILES"` prints `*`, not a list of files.

Answer (score -2):

Its very important to preceed

```
IFS=""
```

otherwise files with two directly following spaces will not be found

Comment: That’s incorrect. Both posted solutions work without change with files that contain two consecutive spaces.