# Assign output from find without word splitting

Tags: arrays, bash, find

While running the bash command

```
myarray="(`find -type d -printf '%d\t%P\n' | cut -f2`)"
```

on my present working directory, and then output the contents of myarray,

```
tLen=${#myarray[@]}

for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ ))
do
        echo "${myarray[$i]}"
done
```

directory names with white space get split.  i.e. The white spaces in the directory name 'My tax documents' aren't automatically escaped and ends up becoming three entries in the array, 'My' 'tax' 'documents' rather then just one name.  However running

```
find -type d -printf '%d\t%P\n' | cut -f2
```

from the command line works just fine.  How do I prevent word splitting when assigning the output of find into an array?

Comment: That isn't array assignment syntax at all.

Comment: BTW, why is `%d` in your format string if you're just throwing it away?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing output of find . -print0 into a bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array)

Comment: If you are using a remotely recent version of `bash`, consider using something like `shopt -s globstar; myarray=( ./**/*/ )` instead.

Answer (score 3):

#### On Doing It Right

You can't safely use a newline as the trailing delimiter after an arbitrary filename: Filenames **can contain newlines**.

The below uses an unambiguous delimiter, and a `read` mechanism that works correctly with all possible filenames:

```
myarray=( )
while IFS= read -r -d $'\t' depth && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  printf 'Found filename %q at depth %d\n' "$filename" "$depth" >&2
  myarray+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find . -type d -printf '%d\t%P\0')

# and to demonstrate reading from the array:
echo "Reiterating that list of filenames:" >&2
printf -- '- %q\n' "${myarray[@]}"
```

Note that we're calling `read` twice -- once to read up to the first tab after the depth, and one to read to the following NUL. One could get *almost* this effect with `IFS=$'\t' read -r -d '' depth filename`, but leading and trailing tabs in filenames could get lost.

---

References:

- [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)
- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

---

#### On What Went Wrong

- `find -type d -printf '%d\t%P\n' | cut -f2` doesn't create a correct list of filenames in the first place. Try creating a file with `touch $'foo\tbar\nbaz\tqux'` to have a particularly fun time here (the literal newline in the filename will be emitted by the `%P` format specifier, causing `baz` to be in the position otherwise containing the depth integer, and `qux` to show up as part of what looks like a completely separate filename.
- By default, spaces and tabs are both part of `IFS`, and thus are both used for string-splitting.
- The syntax

  ```
  foo="(`...`)"
  ```

  ...does not actually create an array at all; it creates a *string* which starts with `(` as its first character and ends with `)`.
- String splitting runs glob expansion in conjunction, so if you have a file named `touch *`, that would be replaced with a list of files in the current directory (thus causing other names to be represented *twice*).

---

Comment: "Filenames can contain newlines."  Villages have burned for less.

Comment: @Jack, A policy of "don't do it or I'll kill you" doesn't help with cases where what you have is (1) a software bug dumping data into a filename (I've been there in a case where this, combined with sloppy scripting, had disastrous consequences); or (2) a crafty attacker (who's never heard your warnings to staff and wouldn't necessarily care if they had) trying to exploit a bug in your code (whether to inject a chosen filename into a list of files to be transferred/deleted/overwritten/whatever, or simply prevent *their* file from being deleted/whatever).