# results of find command into list

Tags: fish

Is there a compact way to store the output of a find command into a list ?

Something like:

```
find / -name "mov*.txt" | read var
```

But in a list in order to store all the paths found.

Comment: `set results (find ...)` will do it -- fish command substitutions splits the results on newlines.

Comment: `bash` and `fish` are two different shells. Please untag the one you're not interested in

Comment: For Bash see [Capturing output of find . -print0 into a bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1116992/4154375).

Comment: It's not clear why you are reading into var. The find command dumps all the paths, so save that to a text file and you have your list of paths. Perhaps you could edit this to show values of what your list looks like to you? Rather than describe how you think to solve it - give the sample data and the sample results. There's a great explainer called [mcve] on how to edit this into a post.