# How can I append an entry to an array in a while loop in bash?

Tags: bash

When I declare an array in bash `$ ARRAY=('ele1' ele2')` I can append an element to it with `$ ARRAY+=('ele3')`.

```
echo ${ARRAY[@]}
ele1 ele2 ele3
```

However, inside a script in a while loop I don't get it to work:

```
FOUNDFILES=$(ls -lA)
LINE_CNT=1
ARRAY=()

echo -e "$FOUNDFILES" | while read line
        do
                ARRAY+=("test")
                LINE_CNT=$((LINE_CNT+1))
        done

echo "${ARRAY[@]}"
echo $LINE_CNT
```

`LINE_CNT` variable delivers the amount of files that were found, but my array stays empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are printing `echo "${FILE_ARRAY[@]}"` instead of `echo "${ARRAY[@]}"`, maybe that lead you to believe that `ARRAY` is empty.

Comment: Right hand side of a pipe runs in a subshell. Use `while ... done < <(echo -e "$FOUNDFILES")` isntead.

Comment: Also, capturing a list of files in a plain variable and `echo -e` are both unsafe ways to handle the file list. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array/1120952#1120952) for a safe way to do it.

Comment: @Socowi That was a copy,paste mistake, edited it. Have confusing file names in my real example.

Comment: @choroba This somehow creates an endless loop in my case, but I think this is the right track. `while ... \ndo \ndoSomething \ndone < <(echo -e "$FOUNDFILES")`

Comment: h0ch5tr4355, `array` seems pointless since it just has "test" in it as many times as there were files found, and `line_count` since `line_count=${#foundfiles[@]};` I think you only need two lines from chepner's entry -, `shopt -s globstar; foundfiles=(./**/"$1");`

Comment: @PaulHodges Of course it is pointless. This script is just a placeholder.  I have this while loop in many scripts and I wondered why I could increment the counter but not modify the array.

Comment: Modified the question that `find` is not the deal since it is not used in my real script, just took it as placeholder for a command that creates multi line ouput

Comment: Ah. The loop in in a subshell, so it can't modify the variable in the parent process. Fix it so you aren't appending the loop to a pipe.

Answer (score 5):

A few things:

1. Don't assume that `find` outputs exactly one file name per line; that breaks in the presence of filenames containing newlines.
2. Don't assume that newlines output by `find` are the only whitespace in the output.
3. Don't use `find` at all when a glob will do.

---

```
shopt -s globstar
foundfiles=(./**/"$1")

declare -a array
line_cnt=1
for f in "${foundfiles[@]}"; do
    array+=(test)
    line_count=$((line_count + 1))
done
```

If your call to `find` is more complex than a glob can handle, and your version of `find` can output null-delimited file names, use

```
# -d for readarray was introduced in bash 4.4; earlier versions
# require something more complex; see Gordan Davidson's answer at
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120952/1126841
readarray -t -d $'\0' < <(find . ... -name "$1" -print0)
```

If your `find` does *not* support outputting null-delimited file names, rethink writing this in `bash`. (You might consider using `zsh`, which has a vastly richer set of glob features that can eliminate many cases where you would otherwise need `find`.)

Comment: How to use this?  `ARRAY=(./**/"$1")` didnt create an array

Comment: Furthermore there are no newlines in file names in my case.

Comment: Ok now I managed it to work. This is indeed very helpful. However this rather advises not to use find, not answering my question of what I was doing wrong namely not considering the creation of a subshell. `FOUNDFILES=$(find . -name "$1")` was just a placeholder, because I have this while loop in many scripts and I wondered why I could increment the counter but not modify the array.

Comment: Don't forget `shopt -s globstar;` - c.f.  [bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

Comment: I find the assertion that one variable updates but the other does not dubious.

Comment: Will directly put this into my bashrc as it seems very helpful