# List Files, List Directores, Separately where Filenames have Spaces

Tags: bash

Im working on a bit of automation and I'm a bit stuck at this one point.  I have came up with several different ways of listing out just files, or just folders of a particular directory.

The simplest being:
`for f in $(find ${source_path} -maxdepth 1 -type f); do echo "${f}"; done`

The problem is when the list is read, files with spaces are appearing as if a new line is added in between each space.

Ex:

```
/path/There
were
several
confirmations
with
united.docx
/path/gfw_list.txt
/path/Emergency_Action_Plan.docx
/path/FirstName
LastName
OL
021015.docx
/path/7temp_disp.docx
```

In the above example `FirstName LastName OL 021015.docx` & `There were several confirmations with united.docx` are the real file names but are given several individual lines.

How can I create a list of all of the files (including the ones with spaces).  I would imagine this same thing would happen when I list out folders but I haven't ran into it just yet.  I'd also potentially be looking for an absolute path for the output.

Comment: The best methods is usually to either use `find ... -exec`, or produce the list with `find ... -print0` and use a `while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do` loop. See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) and ["Capturing output of `find . -print0` into a bash array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array).

Comment: Some of the answers on the linked duplicate are wrong, even as the answer you accepted on this question is currently wrong (it's written by someone who knows what they're doing, so this is probably just an oversight / it may be edited to be more correct later). The links Gordon provided above are a much better resource.

Comment: See also [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), which explicitly lists `for i in $(find ...)` as an antipattern to avoid.

Comment: @GordonDavisson not that good at bash.  Where am I actually sticking in the ${source_path} variable?

Comment: @addohm As the first argument to the `find` command. The full loop would be something like `while IFS= read -r -d '' f <&3; do echo "$f"; done 3< <(find "${source_path}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)` (but you'd presumably replace the `echo` with something else).