# change the path variable of the parent shell in a shell script

Tags: shell

I wanted to change the path environment variable in a shell script.
The path variable should be modified after the execution of the shell script.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways I know of to do this. The first is to run the script in the context of the current shell with either of:

```
. myscript.sh
source myscript.sh
```

but that runs the risk of polluting the current shell with all sorts of stuff.

I'd prefer a solution where the amount of information leakage is minimal. That means still running it as a subshell but outputting the new path on statndard output:

```
PATH=$(myscript.sh)
```

This method is a much better one since the path is the *only* thing that can be affected by the subshell but you have to be careful with what that subshell outputs.

Comment: An obvious 3rd way is "eval", though that's as dangerous as sourcing.  For example, the common terminal-set utility "tset" outputs commands intended for the calling shell to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to source your script instead of executing it.

```
. script.sh
```

or

```
source script.sh
```

Inside of the script it's enough to either export od just set the variable.

When the script is executed, it runs in a separate shell process, and can't easily change parent shell's variables.

More about it here: [Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell)