# How to use the same bash variable between a parent shell and child shell

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, variables

I have a bash script similar to the following:

```
function test
{
   running=$(( $running - 1 ))
}

running=0
test &
echo $running
```

Because the test function is run in a sub shell it doesn't affect the running variable and I get 0 echoed to the screen. I need the sub shell to be able to change the parent shells variables, how can this be done? I have tried export but to no avail.

EDIT Thanks for all the helpful answers, The reason I want to run this function in the background is to allow the running of multiple of functions simultaneously. I need to be able to call back to the parent script to tell it when all the functions are finished. I had been using pids to do this but I don't like having to check if multiple processes are alive constantly in a loop.

Comment: In general it cannot be done. Why are you running the function in a subshell? And in the background? If you tell us what you are trying to do we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Actually, you export "down", but not "up". In this case removing `&` will help, but I believe you really need to run it in background, if put that.

Comment: `(( running-- ))` or `(( --running ))`

Answer (score 2):

You can't really. Each shell has a copy of the environment.

see [Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell)

But for what you are doing in your example, try this as your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function testSO
{    
    running=$(( $running - 1 ));
    return $running;
}
```

and invoke it as:

```
running=$(testSO)
```

If you only want to effectively return a value, then just return the value from the function.

Comment: it is same as just running `testSO` in foreground, but that wasn't the OP wants, I think.

Comment: You're confusing two different ways of "returning" info from a function: returning it as a status (what `return` does), and sending it to stdout (which is what `$(...)` captures).  You need to either use `echo $running` and `running=$(testSO)` or `return $running` and `testSO; running=$?` not a mixture of the two.  Since `running` doesn't appear to be a status indicator (i.e. nonzero doesn't indicate an error), I'd go with the first approach.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not a wiz with subshells, so I appreciate learning more.

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases instead of functions. Or write a script with the function body and execute it with `source`.

Both solutions avoid creating a sub-shell.