# Cannot change RVM gemset from shell script via `rvm gemset use`

Tags: bash, rvm

(See update at bottom)

---

I feel like I'm missing something terribly obvious here, but I can't change gemsets from within a shell script. This minimal script demonstrates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rvm gemset use "testing"
```

I even tried the instructions from the [Scripting RVM page](http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/scripting/) (although it didn't seem necessary):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # First try to load from a user install
  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # Then try to load from a root install
  source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
else
  printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"
fi

rvm gemset use "testing"
```

Still no go.

Interestingly enough, if I try to run the script without first creating the "testing" gemset, I get `ERROR: Gemset 'testing' does not exist, rvm gemset create 'testing' first.` However, if I create the gemset and then run the script, I get no output from the script and the gemset is not changed (according to `rvm info`). I am able to perform *other* RVM gemset actions, such as creating gemsets and trusting `.rvmrc` files, from within the script.

**[Update]**

Of course, the environment *is* changing, as indicated by a call to `rvm info` from within the script. How do I get these changes to persist/affect the calling shell? Or, if that's not possible (as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell)), is there any way to set the current RVM gemset based on input to a script?

Comment: your headline shows you using backquotes. Are you really using them? You know that means command-substitution? any output from that command would have to be in the form of varName=value to be useful (plus most likely, a preceeding eval). Good luck!

Comment: No, I'm not, I just used them in the title to indicate a command.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Had exactly the same problem, and here's the solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# IMPORTANT: Source RVM as a function into local environment.
#            Otherwise switching gemsets won't work.
[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

# Enable shell debugging.
set -x

rvm 1.9.2@gemset_a
rvm gemdir
gem env gemdir

rvm 1.9.2@gemset_b
rvm gemdir
gem env gemdir
```

What I've found out is that your interactive shell has got `rvm()` and its helpers, whereas script's environment **has not** got them. `rvm` binary is executed instead, **partially** working and thus causing some confusion.

Comment: Thanks!  This was killing me with my Jenkins/Capistrano deploy!  I was soooo confused! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! This also helped fix an issue where switching Ruby version (e.g. "rvm system") didn't work inside a script.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash --login` will also do the trick if you don't want to have to add `[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing the functionality I wanted as a function instead of a shell script.

```
function rvmrc {
  rvm gemset create $1
  rvm gemset use $1
  echo "rvm gemset use $1" > .rvmrc
  rvm rvmrc trust
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this solves a bunch of issues for me and can be used with other things.  Seems obvious when you show it here but I've been fiddling with this for hours!

Answer (score 0):

RVM isn't loading correctly because it loads on your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, which are run at login.

You can run the `rvm gemset use` with a login shell:

```
bash -l -c "rvm use RUBY_VERSION@GEMSET_NAME"
```

Hope it helps!