# Execute shell commands from Ruby code

Tags: ruby, user-interface, command-line-arguments

*Note: If you think of a better title/question, feel free to suggest it. I wasn't sure how to articulate this question in one brief sentence.*

I created a command line Mastermind game. To play the game, you type `play.rb` at the command line.

`play.rb` is a Ruby script that fires up the game. Within the script, the game is sent an interface, called `CommandLineInterface`.

If you want to play using a GUI (I'm using a Ruby GUI called Limelight), you `cd` into the `limelight` directory and type `limelight open production` and the GUI opens.

*There is a `mastermind_game` directory that contains a `lib`, a `spec`, and a `limelight` directory. The `limelight` directory contains a `production` directory.*

Now I'm making a few changes. You can pass arguments to the script at the command line. Either you enter `play.rb "command line game"` or `play.rb "limelight game"`.

`ARGV` is an array of the arguments passed at the command line.

```
if ARGV.include?("command line game")
    interface = CommandLineInterface.new
elsif ARGV.include?("limelight game")
    interface = LimelightInterface.new
end
```

If I want to play my command line game, I enter `play.rb "command line game"` and it works fine.

I want to be able to type `play.rb "limelight game"` at the command line and have that open the GUI. In `ARGV`, the argument `"limelight game"` would be found so `interface` would be set to `LimelightInterface.new`. Within my `LimelightInterface` class I want the initialize method to open the GUI. It should essentially have the same functionality as typing `limelight open production` at the command line.

I'm not sure if this is possible or how to do it, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

*EDITED: I'm trying to execute the command `rvm use jruby` by including this line in my script:*

```
system("rvm use jruby")
```

*I get back: "RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work."*

Comment: The system command to select a kind of Ruby shouldn't be necessary; you can choose jruby by using a [.rvmrc](http://bre.overnothing.com/workflow/rvmrc/) file. You can store what you're trying to call in a subdirectory and create a `.rvmrc` file there.

Comment: Okay, I created a .rvmrc file to specify that I want to use jruby. So all I should have to do is add `system("cd limelight")` to my script, correct? Just `cd` into the directory and the .rvmrc file will run jruby. I'm trying to do that, but it doesn't appear to be successfully going into that directory.

Comment: No, an `.rvmrc` file determines *which* Ruby is run when calling `ruby ...`, it does not launch Ruby. You need to `cd` into the directory, then start your script.

Comment: Okay. I added `Dir.chdir("limelight") do`  `system("limelight open production")`  `end`  . It `cd`'s into the limelight directory, but it doesn't use jruby. When I `cd` into the limelight directory manually, however, it use jruby.

Comment: Then that's because the script is executed not as your user account but as something else. Try something like `whoami` and compare what your script says against your usual user account.

Comment: Hmmm...it's the same for both (normal and within my script). The error I get is `sh: limelight: command not found`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16513/discussion-between-rzv-and-robert-k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan, there's several ways to call out to the system:

Backticks:
    `ruby -e 'p ARGV' '1 2' '3 4'`   # => "[\"1 2\", \"3 4\"]\n"

The %x literal (note that you can use any delimiter you like, you're not restricted to parentheses)

```
%x(ruby -e 'p ARGV' '1 2' '3 4') # => "[\"1 2\", \"3 4\"]\n"
```

The `system` command. The difference here is that it passes stdin / out / err on through. (the above return the stdout, this one prints it on your process' stdout).

```
system('ruby', '-e p ARGV', '1 2', '3 4')
# >> ["1 2", "3 4"]
```

And if you need more sophisticated usage, something like [open3](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/open3/Open3) from the stdlib has gotten me pretty far. If you really need the big guns (it doesn't sound like you do), there's a gem [open4](http://rubygems.org/gems/open4).

---

Edit:

It sounds like you're wanting to do something like this:

```
require 'open3'

bash_script = <<SCRIPT
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
rvm use jruby
ruby -v
exit
SCRIPT

out, err, status = Open3.capture3 'bash', stdin_data: bash_script
puts out
# >> Using /Users/joshcheek/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7
# >> jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_29) [darwin-x86_64-java]
```

But honestly, I don't think it's a good solution for your situation, because there's many legitimate ways to set up jruby for your environment. I think it would be better to just check that the limelight binary exists, and tell your user to fix their environment if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I played around with those to see what I could do and the issue I'm running into is that I can't do `shell("rvm use jruby")`. It responds with: "RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work." So the command I'd like to call is `limelight open`, but to do that I first have to do `rvm use jruby`. Not sure how to make that work.

Comment: I found [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792707/cannot-change-rvm-gemset-from-shell-script-via-rvm-gemset-use), but I don't really understand the solution they offered there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first result from googling the title: http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html

If that's not what you need, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yeah, originally my question wasn't worded this way. I was struggling to find an answer on Google because I wasn't sure *what* to Google. After changing the question several times, I finally landed on "Execute shell commands from Ruby code". I did notice that article just a half hour ago so I'm looking over it now.  Now I understand how to use a few things, like backticks and `system`, but I haven't been able to get it to work for my example.