# difference between #./ and #. ./

Tags: linux, bash, dot-source

whats the difference between executing script like

```
# ./test
```

and

```
# . ./test
```

test is simple script for example

```
#!/bin/bash
export OWNER_NAME="ANGEL 12"
export ALIAS="angelique"
```

i know  the results but im unsure what actually happens

Thanks

Comment: I didn't know you could do #. ./blah. Nice tip. :)

Comment: how?? `#` should be a comment and everything behind should be ignored! Except for the `#!` at the beginning of file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`./foo` executed `foo` if it's marked as executable and has a proper shebang line (or is an ELF binary). It will be executed in a new process.

`. ./foo` or `. foo` loads the script in the *current* shell. It is equal to `source foo`

With your example code you need to use the second way if you want the exported variables to be available in your shell.

Comment: why aren't the environment variables not exported in the first scenario .. ? im still confused ..

Comment: @user1127747: See the question [Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell) for an answer to that.

Comment: @user1127747: Because the script runs in a process of its own, it can't export things *back* to its parent's environment. That's just not how environment variables work. With source (the lone dot), you remain in the shell's process, and are thus free to change its environment.

Answer (score 2):

With the dot alone, bash is "sourcing" the specified file. It is equivalent to the `source` builtin and attempts to include and execute the script within the same shell process.

The `./` starts a new process, and the current shell process waits for it to terminate.

Comment: The `./` means *in the current directory*. It's a file path element, not a bash syntax element and won't spawn a subshell.

Comment: @DarkDust: that was maybe imprecise, I just wanted to generalise the case of calling a script without sourcing it.

Answer (score 0):

The first implies that the script (or binary) be executable. With the script (possibly) containing a shebang line telling which interpreter to use.

The second is a short-hand for "execute [argument] as a shell script". The file passed as argument does not need the executable bit set.