# Difference between excuting . script.sh vs ./script.sh

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between “./somescript.sh” and “. ./somescript.sh”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634219/what-is-the-difference-between-somescript-sh-and-somescript-sh)

Please clarify the difference between the shell commands . script.sh vs ./script.sh where script.sh is a shell script.

Thanks

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880735/difference-between-launching-a-script-with-script-sh-and-script-sh?rq=1

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017763/difference-between-and?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

The difference is simple

```
. script.sh
```

executes the shell script using your current shell, so all changes you do in the script (like change directory or variables) will affect your running shell

```
./script.sh
```

on the other hand will start a new shell to execute the script. It is usually the better way to launch scripts