# using "echo" to pass a value through a pipe

Tags: linux, oracle, pipe, echo

I'm using   `Linux 2.6.x.x.x

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (i586)`

The question I want to know is **how to pass a value through a pipe to a command ??**
On every other operating system, including `DOS`, I can use:

```
echo <value> | <command>
```

But on `Linux`, this does not seem to work.

For example, I want to pass a `Database Name` to an `Oracle` command that sets `Environment Variables` for the `Database` based on what it reads from the `oratab` file.

Normally, the command would run as:

```
 . oraenv   (to source environment variable settings)
```

Then, it would prompt you for the Database Name.

But, if I run:   `echo <some_db_name> | . oraenv`  , it works without prompting and is useful in scripts on every platform except this version of Linux.

Any ideas?

```
$ <> /home/oracle>echo $SHELL   
/bin/bash
```

Comment: "This does not seem to work" is not a very good problem description. What goes wrong?

Comment: your `oraenv` runs in a sub shell. environment in subshell can't pass to the main process.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12145810/841108 which is an answer to a very similar question

Answer (score 3):

On Unix, the pipe is used to pass the output of a program in the input of another.

ex:

```
$ echo "b c a e d" | tr " " "\n" | sort 
a
b
c
d
e
```

From http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oraenv

Non-interactive (handy for scripting):

```
$ export ORACLE_SID=orcl
$ export ORAENV_ASK=NO
$ . oraenv
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you already tried something like this?:

> echo "table" | ./oraenv -

Where "-" means /dev/stdin

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to set the user `profile`. Usually, Environment variables are `EXPORTED` inside a `profile` file. But if you want to build your own profile file you can ask the user for values , like

```
echo "Enter the DB Name:"    #This is optional but can be used in case if someone runs the script like $ . ./oraenv
read ORACLE_SID    # ORCL_SID is a variable
. oraenv
```

Once you place something like above in `oraenv` the command `echo <db name>|. ./oraenv` should work.Another method would be use command line arguments like

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]             # $# is the number of arguments passed to the script
then
    echo "DB Name must be entered"
    exit 0
else
    ORACLE_SID =$1             # initialize $1 is the first arg which is the db name, consecutive args can be accessed by $2, $3 and so on.
    . oraenv
fi
```

Once you have the above, the command below should work.

```
$ . ./oraenv oradev
```

Having said all this, the `oraenv` utility is an Oracle utility and you wouldn't be able to edit or modify that utility. So the best way to go with that is `EXPORTING` the variables before running `oraenv`, the solution above would be applicable for a custom `oraenv` script (if you wish to write one).