# empty variable when send to background using export

Tags: bash, for-loop, background

I'm building a sitemap from mysql and to speed things-up I would like to send my function to the background. When I do so, the `"$SITEMAP"` variable appears empty.

what I've tried is setting export `SITEMAP="$SITEMAP"`

```
for ((i=0; i<CNT; i++)); do
    xml() {
        ...
        export SITEMAP="$SITEMAP"
    }
    xml &
    echo -e "$SITEMAP"
done
```

ps: 
without sending to background the "xml" function, script works
correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the background shell is a different process. The rest is explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell).

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
 xml &
```

you start a different process, then the `export` is valid only in the environement of the latter.

Remove the `&` and it will work