# Capture output of a bash command, parse it and store into different bash variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

**Explanation:**

I have a small *bash* script which simply runs *any* Linux command (e.g. say `ifconfig`)

The typical output of *ifconfig* is something like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:F7:0D:6D:34:CA
          inet addr:10.106.145.12  Bcast:10.106.145.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::32f7:dff:fe6d:34ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1104666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2171 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:444437904 (423.8 MiB)  TX bytes:238380 (232.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:15900 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15900 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:467306 (456.3 KiB)  TX bytes:467306 (456.3 KiB)
```

Now what most people usually do is store the *entire* output into a file/variable and parse based on that. I however want to know if there is anyway that I could put *specific* parts of the output in more than one variable (say a *bash variable* called `${IPETH0}` to carry the IP address `10.106.145.12` from *eth0* and `${IPLO}` to carry the IP address `127.0.0.1` from *lo* in the above example *without running ifconfig command twice*).

Something like what *tee* command does with the input but I want to do this for the *output* and store the output into 2 or *more* variables in one go. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you run your script with `source`, you cannot set variables in the calling environment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell

Comment: @Pumbaa80: I did not quite think so far as the exporting of the variables. Thanks for that tidbit nevertheless. :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$ read IPETH0 IPLO <<< $(ifconfig | awk '/inet[[:space:]]/ { print $2 }')
$ echo "${IPETH0}"
192.168.23.2
$ echo "${IPLO}"
127.0.0.1
```

This assumes the order of the `eth0` and `lo` interfaces, but it shows the basic idea.

Comment: How do I change the delimiters?
    This is what I got: $echo ${IPETH0}
    addr:10.106.145.12 
    $echo ${IPLO}
    addr:127.0.0.1

Comment: @Arpith: My `ifconfig` output does not include the address family, my mistake...you can try `read IPETH0 IPLO <<< $(ifconfig | awk -F'[[:space:]:]+' '/inet[^6]/ { print $3 }')` to include the colon as a delimiter.

Comment: Went ahead and used cut. Exactly what I was looking for. Great answer! Thank you. (Note to self: I seriously need to learn awk.)

Comment: Whatever works for you :-) But yes, `awk` is great...just read a few of e.g. [@EdMorton's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) answers and you will soon know most things you will need ;-)

Comment: plus 1, for multi-variable assignment oneliner

Answer (score 4):

You can use awk and bash arrays:

```
arr=( $(awk -F ':' '$1 == "inet addr"{sub(/ .*/, "", $2); print $2}' < <(ifconfig)) )
```

Then you can do:

```
read IPETH0 IPLO <<< ${arr[@]}
```

Comment: This creates a numeric-index array, but doesn't link the IPs to the interface names.

Comment: @Barmar: Agreed, associative arrays are latest edition to newer versions of BASH only. Unfortunately I am on OSX and still on older BASH. However shell variables can be created from this array (as in my edit)

Answer (score 3):

you can read each line of ifconfig and set variables :

```
while read l1 ;do 
   if [[ $l1 =~ inet ]];then     
      set -- $l1 
      echo  "ip is  $2  " 

   fi
done < <(ifconfig)
```

Comment: This keeps setting the same variables each time through the loop, so it won't set different variables for each interface.