# Set environment variable such that it can be read outside my program

Tags: python, linux

Here's my script:

```
try:
    os.environ['CONSOLE'] = '1'
    while True:
        ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    del os.environ['CONSOLE']
```

I'm trying to set an environment variable called `CONSOLE`. While this program is running that variable should exist, once I exit out of it with Ctrl+C it should disappear.

When I leave the program running and try printing it from my shell, however, I get:

```
$ echo $CONSOLE
CONSOLE: Undefined variable.
```

I can't seem to read it from my PHP script either. Where's my variable? I thought `os.environ` should allow me to do this?

Comment: You cannot do this. The variables will not persist and won't be available in the parent shell. You need to pass the information in some other way.

Comment: What's the easiest way to share a single boolean between a Python script and a PHP script then? Polling a file seems a bit lame.

Comment: `echo export CONSOLE=1 >> ~/.bash_rc` then `sh ~/.bash_rc` but I dont think thats quite what your looking for ... what are you actually trying to do? your best be may be to rethink your approach (this reminds me of those XY problems)

Comment: Depends on where they're running. If one launches the other, a command line argument or an environment variable will work. Otherwise, some form of IPC.

Answer (score 7):

It's the nature of how a shell works, each new process is [fork/exec'd](http://www.cs.ecu.edu/~karl/4630/spr01/example1.html), so your Python script is [running in a separate process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell?rq=1) from the shell that started it.

Setting environment variables, through whatever means, won't change the variables in the shell it was  started from because the script's environment and the original shell's environment are distinct.

As you can see here, it's not getting lost after the script, but even while python is still running (bash 4.2, python 3.3)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['CONSOLE'] = '1'
>>> 
[1]+  Stopped                 python3.3
$ echo $CONSOLE

$ fg
python3.3

>>> os.environ['CONSOLE']
'1'
```

If you're trying to effectively get named shared memory between the PHP and Python scripts, you could [use a FIFO](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156) and read/write to as you would a file, or communicate over a socket.

Answer (score 1):

I have a use-case where I have a Python library that is setting some configuration and I needed an environment variable to go along with it - so I wouldn't have to re-enter it EVERY time I used a command.

In my case I ended up using ~/.bash_profile to source a custom function that included an export command as well as a call to the python library.

Code:

Created `~/.okta/okta-awscli` with the following contents:

```
okta-awscli () {
    export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-2"
    python ...PATH TO PYTHON LIBRARY IN VIRTUAL ENV
}
```

Added to ~/.bash_profile: `source ~/.okta/okta-awscli`.

I know it's hacky, but it saves me some time and it was quick.