# incrementing an environmental variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I need to increment an environmental variable by these steps:

```
envar=1
export envar
sh script_incrementation
echo $envar
```

where script_incrementation contains something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
envar=$[envar+1] #I've tried also other methods of incrementation
export envar
```

Whatever I do, after exiting the script the variable remains with its initial value 1.

THanks for your time.

Comment: Are you using bash or sh? Your file indicates sh, but you tagged bash. Note that they are not the same thing.

Comment: That is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A shell script executes in its own shell, so you cannot affect the outer shell unless you source it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell) for details of that discussion.

Consider the following script, which I will call `Foo.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

export HELLO=$(($HELLO+1))
```

Suppose in the outer shell, I define an environmental variable:

```
export HELLO=1
```

If I run the script like this, it run inside its own shell and will not affect the parent.

```
./Foo.sh
```

However, if I source it, it will just execute the commands in the **current** shell, and will achieve the desired affect.

```
. Foo.sh
echo $HELLO # prints 2
```

Comment: it works, thanks man, I can't believe I've spent an entire night wondering what could be wrong.

Comment: @SouthPole, You are welcome. Command line is fun but not always obvious. :)

Comment: It should be`export HELLO=1`. Bash is case-sensitive, but can't edit only one sign.

Comment: worth mentioning that `$(( expression ))` is an [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) that allows *the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and the substitution of the result*.

Answer (score 0):

Your script can not change the environment of the calling process (shell), it merely inherits it.

So, if you `export foo=bar`, and then invoke `sh` (a new process) with your script, the script will see the value of `$foo` (which is `"bar"`), and it will be able to change its own copy of it – but that is not going to affect the environment of the parent process (where you exported the variable).

You can simply `source` your script in the original shell, i.e. run

```
source increment_script.sh
```

or

```
. increment_script.sh
```

and that will then change the value of the variable.

This is because `source`ing a script avoids spawning a new shell (process).

Another trick is to have your script output the changed environment, and then eval that output, for example:

```
counter=$[counter+1]
echo "counter=$counter"
```

and then run that as

```
eval `increment_script.sh`
```

Comment: `$[...]` predates the POSIX standard; use `$((...))` instead.