# v.sh is not exporting the variable using terminal ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I want to export many paths using a .sh script. after running it nothing is exported I don't know why. so if anyone can advise.
This is the script used:

```
#!/bin/bash

txtrst=$(tput sgr0) # Text reset
txtred=$(tput setaf 1) # Red
echo "${txtred}## var ##${txtrst}" 

T_D_L=/home/
T_D=$T_D_L
```

after that I run `echo $T_D_L` but nothing happens

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `./script.sh` to run, and the correct way is `source script.sh`