# How do I export credentials as environment vars from a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've written a shell script, called `credentials.sh`, which contains:

```
export USERNAME = 'user'
export PASSWORD = 'pass'
```

Security of these variables is no big deal.

Two questions.

1. When I run this script, ./credentials.sh (both as root and not), it doesn't actually export the vars. Why is this?
2. What is the preferred way to do so they are universally available (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Comment: Don't run it. Source it. `. credentials.sh` instead of `./credentials.sh`. You need to do that to run it in the current shell and not a new shell.

Comment: Your shell syntax is wrong in that it should be `USERNAME='user'` -- i.e. no space.  This is actually important.

Comment: Run it as a part of the current shell by . ./credentials.sh. That is a dot followed by the file name.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell

Comment: BTW, if you control the variable names, you should consider using ones less likely to conflict with other programs/scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Two changes:

1. Fix your variable assignment syntax:

   ```
   export USERNAME='user'
   ```
2. To make this value always available to user, append the above code line to the file `~/.profile`; this will set the variables during login, such that this will not need to be manually invoked at other times.