# How to make nvm run from within a script influence the environment of the calling shell?

Tags: nvm

When I run nvm from within a shell script, it doesn't seem to impact the environment of the calling shell:

```
$ node -v
v4.1.1
$ env | grep -i node
MANPATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/share/man:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/rvm/man
NVM_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/lib/node
PATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/mnt/shared/bin:/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/.bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/mnt/shared/sbin:/opt/gitl:/opt/go/bin:/mnt/shared/c9/app.nw/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist
NODE_PATH=/mnt/shared/lib/node_modules
NVM_BIN=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin
$ 
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use 0.10.40
nvm alias default 0.10.40
echo NVM_PATH=$NVM_PATH
echo MANPATH=$MANPATH
echo PATH=$PATH
echo NVM_BIN=$NVM_BIN

$ ./test
Now using node v0.10.40 (npm v1.4.28)
default -> 0.10.40 (-> v0.10.40)
NVM_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node
MANPATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.40/share/man:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/rvm/man
PATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/mnt/shared/bin:/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/.bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/mnt/shared/sbin:/opt/gitl:/opt/go/bin:/mnt/shared/c9/app.nw/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
NVM_BIN=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin
$ 
$ node -v
v4.1.1
$ env | grep -i node
MANPATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/share/man:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/rvm/man
NVM_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/lib/node
PATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/mnt/shared/bin:/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/.bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/mnt/shared/sbin:/opt/gitl:/opt/go/bin:/mnt/shared/c9/app.nw/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist
NODE_PATH=/mnt/shared/lib/node_modules
NVM_BIN=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin
$
```

What do I need to do inside script "test" so that "node -v" will give me 0.10.40 after I run "./test" ?

Note that if I open a new terminal, and type "node -v" I get 0.10.40. But for some reason, in the shell in which I executed the "test" script I seem to be stuck with 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash scripts run in their own process context that inherits its environment from the parent process. It's not possible to change the environment of the parent. See [Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell)

But just as your script sources nvm with `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`, you could source your script, which will execute it in the context of the parent shell:

```
$ node -v
v4.1.1
$ ./test
Now using node v0.10.40 (npm v2.14.8)
default -> 0.10.40 (-> v0.10.40)
NVM_PATH=/Users/william/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node
MANPATH=/Users/william/.nvm/v0.10.40/share/man:/Users/william/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/usr/local/MacGPG2/share/man:/Users/william/.rvm/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
PATH=/Users/william/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:~/local/bin:~/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/bin:./node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin
NVM_BIN=/Users/william/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin
$ node -v
v4.1.1
$ source ./test
Now using node v0.10.40 (npm v2.14.8)
default -> 0.10.40 (-> v0.10.40)
NVM_PATH=/Users/william/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node
MANPATH=/Users/william/.nvm/v0.10.40/share/man:/Users/william/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/usr/local/MacGPG2/share/man:/Users/william/.rvm/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
PATH=/Users/william/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:~/local/bin:~/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/bin:/Users/william/.rvm/bin:./node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin
NVM_BIN=/Users/william/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin
$ node -v
v0.10.40
```