# Is it possible to modify the environment variables of the current terminal session from a node process?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to export environment variables to the calling shell/terminal/cmd in a platform agnostic way using node.

Is this possible?

Of course I can set variables using

```sh
FOO="bar"
echo $FOO
```

The following doesn't work but essentially I am hoping to do the same thing from node:

```sh
node -e "process.env.FOO = 'bar'"
echo $FOO
```

Or perhaps using `spawn` or similar?

Comment: Are you looking to modify the environment as the current node process sees it or the environment used by the shell that's running that node process? The former is pretty simple, but the latter I have no clue about.

Comment: The environment used by the shell that's running that node process - so the next program has access to the variables as set by the node script

Comment: According to the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496702/7665043) that's not easily possible, but they do suggest some hack-y ways to do so that may work. Also seems to be a duplicate of this question, at their core.